# Django missing fields after initial makemigration

Tags: python, django

When I run python manage.py makemigrations myapp and check the 0001_initial.py file in my migrations folder, I expected to see every field in my models, however what I see is below:

```
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    initial = True

    dependencies = [
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Data',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(auto_created=True, primary_key=True, serialize=False, verbose_name='ID')),
                ('original_file', models.TextField(max_length=255)),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
                'db_table': 'acoustic_data',
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Sites',
            fields=[
                ('site_name', models.TextField(primary_key=True, serialize=False)),
            ],
            options={
                'managed': False,
                'db_table': 'site',
            },
        ),
    ]
```

you can see that the Data model only has 'original_file' field while I was expecting also 'data_id', 'site_id', 'date_recorded', 'time_recorded' and 'average'. For the Site model 'site_id' is also missing. I am wondering why only the last field shows up?

Below is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Sites(models.Model):
    site_id = models.TextField(primary_key=True)
    site_name = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False # this means Django should never alter this table
        db_table = 'site'


class Data(models.Model):
    data_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    site_id = models.ForeignKey(Sites, db_column='site_id', to_field='site_id')
    date_recorded = models.DateField('%Y-%m-%d')
    time_recorded = models.TimeField('%H:%M:%S')
    average = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True, default=None)
    original_file = models.TextField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False # this means Django should never alter this table
        db_table = 'acoustic_data'
```

I also referred to this question already [Django makemigrations omists some fields from model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37276758/django-makemigrations-omists-some-fields-from-model)  but it didn't seem to work for me.

Comment: If it is 0001 version ~> You makemigrations for the first time.

Please **delete it** and **create again** (may be you makemigrations when the models don't complete yet)

If this problem stay still please edit for more detail (the console log)

Comment: oh yes that works, thank you

Comment: I am not sure why this question deserves a downvote, I don't think someone new to Django should be penalized for not knowing this

Comment: Why is this downvoted? I encountered the same issue, and even deleting the old migration file can't resolve it...

Comment: @RaymondChen do you have a solution to this? I have the same issue and deleting files doesn't help either.

Comment: @SwapnilB. Sorry I think I didn't. I already changed company and didn't work on it anymore.

Comment: @SwapnilB. Did you ever find a solution this? I think I am facing the exact same problem.

Comment: @NamNguyễn I have the same problem as this question and deleting the 0001 version and creating it again does not work. Do you have any other ideas about how to fix this problem?

Comment: @A_Quack Deleting and again running migration is the workaround I used. Not sure if there is a better way to solve this.

Comment: @SwapnilB. that helps. I also had commas at the end of each line in my models.py. When I removed the commas and tried your solution it worked.

Comment: @A_Quack I don't work with python for long. Don't remember to find out the way. Congras on work it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is 0001 version ~> You makemigrations for the first time.

Please **delete it** and **create again** (may be you makemigrations when the models don't complete yet)

If this problem stay still please edit for more detail (the console log)