# django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Category) specified for TblDetails?

Tags: python, django

ok. so when i tried to makemigrate for model class,earlier all fields were not visible inside migration>0001_initials. 
so i use this solution

[Django missing fields after initial makemigration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44450605/django-missing-fields-after-initial-makemigration)

deletig and using makemigration does't work for me. so i edited my code and added the missing field. it work fine for me and all the fields were created in my postagesql database(including Category field).
but now when i tried to create form using model. it is raising error

*model.py*

```
class TblDetails(models.Model):
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100),
    ImgUrl = models.CharField(max_length=255),
    FileName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

*forms.py*

```
class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TblDetails
        fields = ('Category','FileName')
```

*page.html*

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="col-md-10 offset-md-1 mt-5">
  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1 class="display-4">Upload Files</h1>
    <hr class="my-4">
    <form action="" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form|crispy}}

    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**and the error raised in terminal**

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (Category) specified for TblDetails
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your model has "," at the end, that is why the migrations were not working

```
class TblDetails(models.Model):
    Category = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ImgUrl = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    FileName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

fields in the form should be an array

```
class DetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = TblDetails
        fields = ['Category','FileName']
```

[see this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/)